# Orange3 / python script / scipy interpn

Tags: orange, scipy

I tried to create a learner using the Orange canvas script from the Python script widget, but I have not been able to find an effective example.

What I would like to do is:

1. Create a learner based on `scipy.interpolate.interpn` (or other interp, this is to get an example)
2. Have the training dataset come from an Orange table (with target defined)
3. Have the output result be the same as existing learners, for example knn

I tried to gain inspiration from existing widgets like the knn one, but when I copied and pasted the code in the script, nothing happened.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Or, scipy examples to share?

Accessing to the scipy functions could be very helpful, for example to compare interpolation and regression output results.

Thanks.